# Correctly moving around types with JSON::PullParser

Tags: json, crystal-lang

In a Crystal shard I am creating, data needs to be pulled from different API endpoints. Collection endpoints will respond with a array like the one below:

```
json = %({
  "_embedded": [
    {"id":"item_1"},
    {"id":"item_2"}
  ]
})
```

To interpret the array and cast it to an array of objects, I prepared the following converter:

```
struct ListConverter(T)
  def self.from_json(pull : JSON::PullParser)
    items = Array(T).new
    pull.read_array do
      items.push(Item.from_json(pull.read_raw))
    end
    items
  end
end
```

There are two abstract structs. One for the items in the array and another for the list itself, which includes `Enumerable`:

```
abstract struct Base
  include JSON::Serializable
end

abstract struct List(T) < Base
  include Enumerable(T)

  @[JSON::Field(key: "_embedded", converter: ListConverter(Item))]
  getter items : Array(T)

  def each(&block : T -> _)
  end
end
```

Finally, the implementation:

```
struct Item < Base
  getter id : String?
end

struct ItemList < List(Item)
end

list = ItemList.from_json(json)
```

This all works fine, except for one thing. The list converter needs to be passed the exact item type:

```
@[JSON::Field(key: "_embedded", converter: ListConverter(Item))]
```

I would like to be able to do this, but of course, that does not work because `T` is not defined at runtime (I think):

```
@[JSON::Field(key: "_embedded", converter: ListConverter(T))]
```

So now I will have to define the following lines in every struct inheriting from `List`:

```
@[JSON::Field(key: "_embedded", converter: ListConverter(Item))]
getter items : Array(T)
```

What would be the best approach to avoid unnecessary duplication?

Comment: I'm not sure if your actual use case has something else going on. But in the sample you posted here, you shouldn't need a custom `ListConverter` at all. That's already covered by `Array`. Just omitting the `converter: ` config should work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it could convert an array as is. Good to know. Although, in my scenario the array is nested inside an object. Something like this: `{ "_embedded": { "items": [{"id":"item_1"},{"id":"item_2"}] } }`. And the key (`items`) varies based on the name of `T`.

Comment: That should work, too. There's a `root` property on `JSON::Field` for this. See https://carc.in/#/r/8mhf for example.

Comment: Even better! Now I no longer need a converter. Thanks again! https://github.com/wout/mollie.cr/blob/master/src/mollie/list.cr#L3-L9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a brisk walk, I came up with a solution that works. By using a macro, `T` can be captured and the macro can be used to pass the converter to the `JSON::Field` annotation:

```
abstract struct List(T) < Base
  include Enumerable(T)

  macro list_converter
    ListConverter({{ T.id }})
  end

  @[JSON::Field(key: "_embedded", converter: list_converter)]
  getter items : Array(T)

  def each(&block : T -> _)
  end
end
```

Not sure if this is the right/best approach, but it works as expected.